# How to resolve a problem in typescript when migrate my angular project from 14v to 16v?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My project works fine and when update the angular version from 14 to 16 when I tried the ng serve throws an error and this is it:

Error: src/app/paginas/descripcion/descripcion.component.ts:1084:46 - error TS2839: This condition will always return 'true' since JavaScript compares objects by reference, not value.

1084                     if (data != undefined || data != []) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error occurs when comparing object and array literals in typescript.

In many languages, operators like == perform what’s called "value" equality on objects. For example, in Python it’s valid to check whether a list is empty by checking whether a value is equal to the empty list using ==.

```
if people_at_home == []:
    print("people_at_home")
```

This is not the case in JavaScript, where == and === between objects (and therefore, arrays) check whether both references point to the same value.

```
if (peopleAtHome === []) {
// This condition will always return 'false' since JavaScript compares objects by reference, not value.
    console.log("people_at_home")
}
```

what you can you is

```
 if (typeof data !== 'undefined' || data.length > 0)
```

Comment: In my  case I have to do some modifications with your answer, like put the data as any and add the symbol ! next to data, so im really thankful, this works now  this.servicioProductos.getImagenes(this.productoSKU).subscribe((data: any) => {
          if (typeof data !== 'undefined' || data!.length > 0) {